# process output if empty

Tags: c#, process

I am using c# and StandardoutputRedirect to get the output of my process in a string, but the problem that the program sometimes doesn't give any output how ever the process still waiting for an output how can I for example wait for 3 seconds if there is no output continue the program??

Here is my code

```
Process tcpdump = new Process();
tcpdump.StartInfo.FileName= "/usr/sbin/tcpdump";
tcpdump.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
tcpdump.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i en1 -c 10 -nn tcp and src host " + ip + " and port " + ports[i];
tcpdump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
tcpdump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
tcpdump.Start();
tcpdump.WaitForExit(3000);
string tcpdump_output = tcpdump.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // at this part the programs waits for an output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `tcpdump.WaitForExit(3000);`, which should only have your Process waiting for that long, but you may also want to kill it to move on:

```
if (!tcpdump.WaitForExit(3000)) {
    tcpdump.Kill();
}
```

Also, per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx), you should call `.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` *before* calling `WaitForExit()`, otherwise you can enter a deadlock - which it appears you are. So, try updating your code to:

```
string tcpdump_output = tcpdump.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if (!tcpdump.WaitForExit(3000)) {
    tcpdump.Kill();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but what does this line actually means ?? if the process is not closed after 3000 milli seconds kill it ??

Comment: Correct; `WaitForExit(3000)` will wait for 3000 milliseconds for the process to exit and if it doesn't exit, it will return `false`; upon returning `false`, your application will then kill the process it just started.

Comment: Nice... Working perfectly dude :) :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you then you check

```
if (tcpdump.EndOfStream)
{
    // ...
}
```

before reading to the end?